# 8 Queen problem : Why recursive function keeps executing if while condition is false

Tags: c, recursion, while-loop

I solved 8 queen problem without understanding why the recursive function keeps executing if the condition of `while loop` is `false`.

The code with solution provided bellow works perfect. That prints all posible solutions and total count of solutions.

The logic of code is to check if the current columns row is not under attack of any before placed queen, if it is not - place the queen and move to next column, if it is - check the same columns next row.

When `place_queen(int col)` is called for first time I pass parameter 0 , witch means that program starts to look for the solutions starting with column 0.

So i have a chess board in front of me and i am fallowing to my code with it. I filled col 0,1,2,3 and 4  `table[0] = 1; table[1] = 3; table[2] = 5; table[3] = 2; table[4] = 4;`

Now I am on col 5 and this column has no safe rows. I reach `table[5] = 9` that means that i am finished with while loop, because condition `table[5] <= 8` is false.

My questions are:

1. Why the code keeps executing if the condition of while loop is false when I reach for first time 5th columns 9th row?
2. Why the program from column 5 goes back to column 4 and continues loking for next safe row if in the code there is no place indicating that?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int count = 0;
int table[8] = {};

int     is_safe(int col) 
{
int c = col - 1;
int i = 1;  

while(c >= 0)
{   
    if( table[col] == table[c] || table[col] == table[c] - i  || (table[col]) ==  table[c] + i)  
            return 0;
    i++;    
    c--;
}

return 1;
}


void    place_queen(int col)
{   
    table[col] = 1;
    while(table[col] <= 8)
    {
        if(is_safe(col))
        {
            if(col == 7)
        {           
            count++;
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                printf("%d", table[i]);

            printf("\n");
        }
        else
            place_queen((col + 1));
    }

    table[col]++;
    }   
}


int      eight_queens(void)
{   
    place_queen(0);

    return count;
}
```

P.S. Column indexes are 0 to 7 and indexes of rows are 1 to 8.

Comment: col starts at 0, soc starts at -1 which is not `>= 0`

Comment: @stark could you explane me a bit more? I call `place_queen(0)` passing 0 as column index. When it gets inside `place_queen` first thing what i do is  `table[col] = 1`

Comment: He means that you call `is_safe(0)` initially, which means that inside that `c` becomes `-1` and you use that as an index into `table`.

Comment: When asking why a program does not work, please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: in C, all arrays have valid indexes from 0 through (number of elements in array -1).

Comment: the chess board has the arrangement of 8 rows, where each row contains 8 columns.  so `int table[8] = {};` does not represent a chess board.  Suggest: `int table[8][8] = {};`  and the first index is 'rows' and second index is 'columns`  I.E. a total of 64 locations, not the OPs code of 8 locations

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error I call `is_safe(0)` first time and that returns me 1 - it means is safe. But when i reach 5th column `c = col - 1 = 4`. There is no way to get -1. So  `is_safe` returns 0 or 1 depending if is or not safe. When I reach 5th columns 8th row and `is_safe` returns me 0 function `place_queen` is not called anymore and the row becomes 9, that means that condition `table[col] <= 8` is not true. shlouldn't the function stop executing in this case?

Comment: @user3629249  You don't need a whole chessboard to solve the 8 Queens problem.  It is given that there will be 1 queen per column, so you just need which row it is in.  OP has it correct.

Comment: @ph7  Your is_safe code is ok.  I didn't look closely enough at what it does.

Comment: @ stark Any idea then why `place_queen` function keeps executing after reaching 5th column? Here you can run the code with online compiler  https://onlinegdb.com/BkXfjavxB  How you can see, this code prints out all solutions

Comment: regarding: *Now i am on col 5 and this column has no safe rows, also table[col] > 8 that means that i am finished with while loop*  Actually what this means is the current first 4 columns will not work as currently placed.  So the code needs to backup (at least) 1 column and select a different row, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call with `col==5` doesn't keep going. It returns and then the call with `col==4` increases row for column 4 and keeps going. Something like this:

- place_queen(4): the loop executes 3 times so the rows are `13524`, then `is_safe(4)` returns true and `place_queen(5)` is called.

  - place_queen(5): the loop executes 8 times, `is_safe(5)` is never true and the function exits
- place_queen(4): continues, it finishes the loop iteration and executes it 3 more times so the rows are `13528` and `is_safe(4)` is true again.

  - place_queen(5): the loop executes 8 times, `is_safe(5)` is never true and the function exits
- place_queen(4): continues, etc...

Comment: Actualy that is my question. Why it returns to `col 4` and increses the row if the while condition is not anymore true as `table[col] <= 8` because at this point `table[5] == 9`

Comment: Because `place_queen(4)` is a separate function call from `place_queen(5)`. If you have function `foo()` and inside it you call function `bar()`, then when function `bar()` exits you are back in `foo()` and continue. It's similar with recursive call, only the function name is the same and arguments differ. So you are in a middle of a loop in `place_queen(4)` when you call `place_queen(5)`. `place_queen(5)` executes _its own_ loop and exists. Then you continue the loop in `place_queen(4)`.